# Get the start page of a given url

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I'm trying to get the landing page of a website, for example:

```
www.mypage.com/
```

goes to

```
www.mypage.com/default.aspx
```

The landing page is `default.aspx`, so what I need is to identify if the loaded page is the same by entering an url, basically the following:

input:

```
www.mypage.com/ = www.mypage.com/default = www.mypage.com/default.aspx
```

ouput:

```
default.aspx
```

All those entrances redirect the user to the same page that is the start page, and the url is entered by an input field.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do you mean the default document defined in IIS?
If yes, this is defined at website level

Comment: I think this could be done fairly easily using WatiN http://watin.org/

Answer (score 0):

Using [WatiN](http://watin.org/) you can make a simple test method.  Something like this should accomplish what you want.

UPDATE:  I think I understand your question a little better now.  I think you just want to get the landing page.  This should work for you.

```
public string GetHomePage()
{
    string startURL = "http://www.mypage.com/";
    string[] splits = null;

    using (var browser = new IE(startURL))
    {
        string browserURL = browser.Url;
        splits = browserURL.Split(new string[] { startURL }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    }

    return splits[1];
}
```

Comment: This seems to be Unit Testing, can I make this method boolean and invoke it from a non _Testing_ method?

Comment: Yeah you sure can!  Remove the top part, change the return type and make the assert an if statement.  I can update my answer when I get to a computer

Comment: I installed WatiN and made the testing but i can't make it work, do you know a way to get the start page of a Url? based on my own example, if I enter `www.mypage.com/`  i get `default.aspx`

Comment: Yes, your update is correct, I need to know the landing page from a given url, I already tested your code at first I had some dll problems with `Interop.SHDocVw`, then with the properties, I made it to work by calling the method using a _thread_, but the `splits` array contains only empty strings, did you try it using a real page? I don.t know if i'm doing something wrong

Comment: If it only has empty strings it probably means that there is no landing page.  Yeah when I tried it on a real page it was working correctly.

Comment: You can also change `Embed Interop Types` to false on `Interop.SHDocVw` and that will make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:
    `

```
string url = "http://google.com";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
     string redirect = response.Headers["Location"];
     if (redirect != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Redirected to " + redirect);
}
```

Comment: I tried using this code, but I'm always getting a null value in the `redirect` variable, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Even with google? I tested it and it does the redirect. For the website you are testing is is possible that it doesn't do a redirect indeed.

Comment: Yes, I also tested with a local web site where I just set the Start Page, but i get a null value